# How to call function in angular2 using typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to call trimObj inside `ngOnit` but throws error , what is correct implementation when you use function in angular2 using typescript. New to typescript I will appreciate the help.

app.component.ts

```
    export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
        displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
        dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Element[]>;
        socket = io();
        constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {};
        ngOnInit() {
        this.socket.on('newMessage', (event) => {
                         console.log('New Event', event);
                          let data = trimObj(event);
                          this.dataSource.data.push(data);
                           this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data]
                          console.log("DATA",this.dataSource.filteredData);
                       });
                });
        }
        trimObj(obj) => {
              var neededKeys = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
              var newObj = {};
              neededKeys.forEach(function (key) {
                newObj[key] = obj[key];
              });
              return newObj;
            }
    }

export interface Element {
    ticketNum: number;
    ticketOpened: number;
    eventType: string;
    riskIndex: string;
    riskValue: number;
    severity: string;
    lastModifiedDate: number;
    assetID: string;
}
```

Error

```
ERROR in app.component.ts(29,17): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
app.component.ts(29,20): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
app.component.ts(38,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Comment: Your syntax is a mess. There is an extra `});` after `console.log("DATA",this.dataSource.filteredData);`. `trimObject` is it a method or a field taht conatins an error function ?

Comment: i am trying to call function that return the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just call it with **this**

```
this.trimObj(event);
```

You have actually other syntax issues. This is your corrected code:

```
export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = [
        'ticketNum',
        'assetID',
        'severity',
        'riskIndex',
        'riskValue',
        'ticketOpened',
        'lastModifiedDate',
        'eventType'
    ];

    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Element[]>;

    socket = io();

    constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.socket.on('newMessage', event => {
            console.log('New Event', event);
            const data = this.trimObj(event);
            this.dataSource.data.push(data);
            this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data];
            console.log('DATA', this.dataSource.filteredData);
        });
    }

    trimObj(obj): Element {
        const neededKeys = [
            'ticketNum',
            'assetID',
            'severity',
            'riskIndex',
            'riskValue',
            'ticketOpened',
            'lastModifiedDate',
            'eventType'
        ];
        const newObj: Element = <any>{};
        neededKeys.forEach(function(key) {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        });
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this `let data = this.trimObj(event)` but it still throws same error i mentioned in question.

Comment: ERROR app.component.ts(22,45): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: oh it should be array, no but data did not start streaming yet ?

Comment: @hussain I updated the answer. The trimObj() method is updated.

Comment: this is being added as an array i want to push as object if i try `const newObj: Element[] = {};`  does not work

Comment: i added export Element function to question

Comment: sorry to bug you but i tried your updated answer and all possible scenarios still throwing errors `ERROR in app.component.ts(22,45): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Element'.
app.component.ts(40,20): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
  Property 'ticketNum' is missing in type '{}'.
`

Comment: Would be much easier if you provide live example - for example [here](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: sorry dont have access to most of external sites like plunker,jsfiddle ad this one

Comment: Thanks for the help i need to dip more from here

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `trimObj` as a class method ... you are also trying to define it inline as an arrow function which is a syntax error.

*Actually there are a couple of syntax errors* -- remove the extra `});` as well.

There are a couple of solutions:

#### Use as class method.

```
let data = this.trimObj(event);
...
trimObj(obj) {
```

Remove the `=>` as this is causing a syntax error. Now, `trimObj` is properly defined as a class method and you can call it with `this.trimObj()`.

#### Use as separate function

As `trimObj` has no specific relationship to the `StreamComponent` class and is a utility function, you can define it separately and perhaps in its own file:

```
export function trimObj(obj) {
```

Then in `StreamComponent` you can `import { trimObj } from './utilties'` (import is not necessary if it's defined in the same file) and call it with `trimObj()`.